# How do I add prototype-like properties to an existing object?

Tags: javascript

I start off with an simple object like:

```
var person = { name: 'Joe', age: 21 };
```

I want to add a method to this object without the method showing up when I use hasOwnProperty.
So for example, let's create a birthday method that just increments the person's age.

```
var birthday = function() { this.age++; };
```

How do I add this to the person object so if I say:

```
for(var i in person) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

I would get:

```
name: 'Joe'
age: 21
birthday: function() { ... }
```

But if I say:

```
for(var i in person) {
  if(person.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i, person[i]);
  }
}
```

I would get:

```
name: 'Joe'
age: 21
```

Comment: Don't start off with a simple object, but an object that has a prototype to which you can assign your `birthday` method.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? I suspect you're looking for non-enumerable properties, not inherited ones.

Comment: This is my actual problem. Think of what Lodash does with its chaining. If you do _({}) there are methods you can call from that, but they don't show up in a loop using hasOwnProperty. This is the kind of functionality I'm trying to duplicate.

Comment: Lodash creates instances using the standard JS constructor+prototype pattern. But you still have not explained *why* you would want to duplicate this looping functionality. In general, we'd want methods (non-data members) not to show up in any loop that doesn't use special reflection methods. So what is your use case for that?

Comment: using Lodash again as an example, what if I wanted a .each() method on person, and it should loop through .name and .age, but skip .each because it's not really a method of that object, but a helper method that I'm trying to emulate coming from a prototype.

Comment: "*what if I wanted a .each() method on person, and it should loop through .name and .age*" - So that's your goal. You can easily achieve that with a method that explicitly accesses only those two, or you make the method non-enumerable and use a normal loop. There is absolutely no reason to try to "*emulate coming from a prototype.*" - this is a) impossible (you cannot emulate that, it needs to actually be a prototype) and b) not helping to achieve the goal.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. In re-evaluating what I really wanted out of this, I decided that Keith's answer is pretty much what I need, and am forgetting the IE6-IE8 support as those are obsolete at this point. Thanks for your help in explaining this to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var person = { name: 'Joe', age: 21 };

Object.defineProperty(person, 'birthday', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function() { this.age++; }
});

function showPerson() {
  for(var i in person) {
    if(person.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      console.log(i, person[i]);
    }
  }
}

showPerson();
person.birthday();
showPerson();
```

If iterating methods is without hasOwnProperty is important,.
Then the following idea might work..

```js
var person = { name: 'Joe', age: 21 };

var extend = {
  birthday: function () { this.age ++ }
}

var person = Object.assign(
  Object.create(extend),
  person);
  

function showPerson() {
  for(var i in person) {
    if(person.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      console.log(i, person[i]);
    }
  }
}

function showPersonFull() {
  for(var i in person) {
    console.log(i, person[i]);
  }
}

showPerson();
person.birthday();

showPersonFull();
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants. He wants `birthday` to show up in a usual loop.

Comment: Keith, that works great for browsers that support ES5 (which most do these days). Do you know of any way to do this for older browsers (IE6 for example)? I know that might be asking a lot, and I know IE6 is obsolete at this point, just wondering.

Comment: `Do you know of any way to do this for older browsers (IE6 for example)?`  , you could try an es5 shim.. eg. https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim

Answer (score 0):

Add it as another property.

```
person.birthday = function() { this.age++; };
```

```js
var person = { name: 'Joe', age: 21 };
person.birthday = function() { this.age++; };
for(var i in person) {
  console.log(i);
}
person.birthday();
console.log(person.age);
for(var i in person) {
  if(person.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i, person[i]);
  }
}
```